# How do I Hold the computation for a list or table of fractions?

Tags: list-manipulation

How do I create a table of fractions of numbers that are in scientific notation that suppresses the evaluation? I've tried using Hold and HoldForm but it always results in error.

```
particleclass = {10^-6, 10^-5, 10^-4, 10^-3, 10^-2, 10^-1};

alphaTESTwith = {5.261524149346547`*^-11, 5.261524149346548`*^-9, 
   5.261524149346547`*^-7, 0.000052615241493465474`, 
   0.005261524149346548`, 0.5261524149346547`};

alphaTESTwithout = {1.4251746149271436`*^-11, 
   1.4251746149271434`*^-10, 1.4251746149271435`*^-9, 
   1.4251746149271436`*^-8, 1.4251746149271436`*^-7, 
   1.4251746149271436`*^-6};

kappa = {1.32751827`*^8, 1.32751827`*^10, 1.32751827`*^12, 
   1.32751827`*^14, 1.3275182700000002`*^16, 1.32751827`*^18};

l = 1;

alphaKWith = Table[(alphaTESTwith*l)/kappa[[Mass]], {Mass, 1, 6}];
alphaKWithout = 
  Table[(alphaTESTwithout*l)/kappa[[Mass]], {Mass, 1, 6}];

gridWith = Grid[
  Insert[Transpose[
    Insert[Transpose[alphaKWith], N@particleclass, 1]]
   , Prepend[N@particleclass, "Table"], 1],
  Frame -> All]

gridWithout = Grid[
  Insert[Transpose[
    Insert[Transpose[alphaKWithout], N@particleclass, 1]]
   , Prepend[N@particleclass, "Table"], 1],
  Frame -> All]
```

Gives out
[image: Table Results]

Comment: Since `l` does not appear in the tables, you must have set its value; however, you did not include this value in your code. It is unclear which fractions you want held. This does not appear to be a minimal example. Please show what the intended output should look like for a minimal example.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2465451).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not specify "l" I set it arbitrarily to 1. Then you can use "ReplaceAll" together with NumberFormat" to write everything in scientific notation. E.g.:

```
l = 1; 
Grid[Insert[
    Transpose[Insert[Transpose[alphaKWith], N@particleclass, 1]], 
    Prepend[N@particleclass, "Table"], 1] /. 
   x_?NumberQ -> ScientificForm[x], Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful in fixing the decimal numbered labels above and at the side into scientific form. But I also have another question, how do I convert the scientific numbers on the inside to fractions?

Comment: Why do you want to write a real number as fraction? In general, a real number can not be converted into a fraction without error. And to get some precision you need large denominators. Therefore, what exactly do you want. Something ungainly like 396343/1000000000000000000000000?

Comment: I mean that I wanted to write the expression of the variables alphaTESTwith / kappa and alphaTESTwithout / kappa as fractions but does not evaluate the fraction. I wanted it to be expressed in the form of a scientific number divided by a scientific number.

Comment: Try: `MapThread[ScientificForm[#1]/ScientificForm[#2] &, {alphaTESTwith, kappa}]`